# Run C# app on a schedule: Sensible approach?

Tags: c#, automation, scheduled-tasks

I need to automate a couple of basic data import steps using C# and run them once per business day.  I know that I can do this with one or a combination of the following:

1. Standalone app that maintains its own schedule
2. Windows service that maintains its own schedule
3. Standalone app that's run by Windows task automation
4. Standalone app that's run by some other automation tool (SQL Scheduler, Stonebranch, etc).

I'm leaning toward #3, as it will allow for the most code reuse, given the existing architecture of the application and server landscape we have, here.

However, is this the sensible approach?  Am I inadvertently MacGuyvering something?

Comment: Yeah go for option 3, simple and effective.  No point writing your own scheduler if windows scheduler does the job, no point writing a windows service unless it needs to run continuously in the background.

Comment: Have you considered SQL Integration Services (SSIS) since this is a data import? If you are just moving data from one file or datastore to another, I would strongly recommend SSIS.